# Not found how to start implementation of BACNet device

Tags: c++, c, bacnet

I'm working on a custom Linux BACNet compatible device. I've stopped my search on [BACNet Stack](http://bacnet.sourceforge.net/).

I've been able to build from the latest version on github, also been able to test both **readprop** and **writeprop** with **server** from the build directory (examples provided). I had to edit the **writeprop** to make it properly work, but this is not the point here.

Now, I'm wondering what is the good way to implement a device that will answer to read-property requests. In the **server** example, there is one handler that could be the way :

```
    apdu_set_confirmed_handler(
    SERVICE_CONFIRMED_READ_PROPERTY, handler_read_property);
```

but I'm confused when I go into source of **h_rp.c** I see the function **Device_Read_Property** is called, which make more sense to overload? This function seems to belong to **device.h**.

So, should I overload **Device_Read_Property** ? Seems like the library is missing a device implementation comprehensive example.

Comment: I can't comment on BACStack directly, but I do wonder if either a C# or NodeJS if not Java library might be slightly slicker to work with; are you tied to using 'C' as your language of choice?

Comment: @DennisVM-D2i, well my project is in C++, I don't mind using a C library, but it's not just clear what is the good way to integrate the "server" part into an application.

Comment: What' I'm trying to say is that the other libraries might be quicker if not possibly easier to work with - at least in terms of getting a device working quicker.

Comment: @DennisVM-D2i Yes that's what I understood, but the C++ application I want to add BACNet support is already developped and won't be migrated to another language.

Comment: As much as you could wrap it with CLR+ (/.NET's managed C++ for C# integration), the better approach might be via a HTTPS web-API/web-service or direct via BACnet/IP; so you could mock something up quickly, with say NodeJS & the 'bacstack' package, to buy you time to figure out the BACnetStack equivalent in the background.  YABE as a demo server with it.

Comment: @DennisVM-D2i For me, having another platform will only add more work on future maintenance.

Comment: It wasn't about trying to provide you a replacement platform, it was more about giving you a quick alternative sample, that you might learn & (for a short while) benefit from, to just possibly allow you to better diagnose/see the issue with your own code; e.g. for example, a working NodeJS sample can be working (in a very basic way) in minutes.   ;)